# How do I add "My Organization" to permissions of a secondary calendar in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, permissions, calendar

My main calendar has a default permission set up for "My Organization". This allows people to see my busy times or whatever I set it to. How do I add this blanket permission to all other calendars? I can't be adding people individually and I have quite a few different calendars.

Answer (score 0):

As the Default permission level is set to Reviewer, the free/busy information is accessible by the internal users: Right click on the calendar you want to share, select properties
[image]

If you can't see the permission, refer to this article to modify your registry:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/user-experience-changes-for-sharing-a-calendar-in-outlook-5978620a-fe6c-422a-93b2-8f80e488fdec?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us